# Close WebDriver instance forcefully after test ends

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Often after failures of my Test the browser instance is left open.
I make sure to call `quit()` method @AfterSuite ends, still sometimes due to pop-up or not sure what the browser instance is not closed. Here is the sample code I invoke after every Test Suite ends

```
if (_driver.getWindowHandles().size() > 1) {
    _driver.close();
}
if (isAlertPresent()) {
    getAlert();
}
_driver.quit();
if (isAlertPresent()) {
    getAlert();
}
```

Wherein, I first check if there are more windows to close, I close them first and incase a pop-up appears after closing of window I accept that alert box, and later I try to invoke the quit method.

Not sure why the browser instances are left open. Can anyone please help me out understand this process in better way.

Selenium Version 2.40.0

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the method call `driver.quit()` is dead code.

To handle opened window, you need to try the below code,

```
 Set windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
 Iterator windowiterator=windows.iterator();
 while(windowiterator.hasNext())
 {
    windowiterator.next().close();
    //handle your pop up here, if any. 
 }
```

Comment: I too believe everything should be closed once the `quit()` is called, when I run a huge number of test at once I see atleast 10-15 browser instances being stuck on the last task that was being performed, seen on FirefoxDriver & InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: If you have multiple tests, then you should close them right after every test executions. No need to wait till the end of whole suite. define a @AfterTest method and clear your driver there.

Comment: No, since the Test are in flow with each other we want to end it after all test ends, hence it is @AfterSuite. But the problem is instances are sometimes closed by 5-10 out of 100 are left open sometimes, which is totally random

Comment: Can you please help me to understand your scenario better? What do you mean by "since the Test are in flow with each other " ? You mean the application flow ? How many Web driver instances you have in your code?

Comment: Only WebDriver instance is used for running single Test Suite, after TestSuite ends, the WebDriver instance is quited and for new Suite new  instance is created. Every suite has a flow of Application which is maintained through multiple number of test to be performed. But sometimes this instances don't quit as expected and browser instance's are left open, so its random everytime, could be selenium issue, but I am looking for work around if any possible. For IE & Chrome I am doing a forceful kill, I guess I should do the same for firefox too, but is there any other option we can think of?

Comment: in a nutshell, Are you looking to close the driver after every suite. Also, driver.quit() method is not working for multiple instances ? Am i right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49384/discussion-between-rsakhale-and-karthikeyan)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried driver.quit(). As per Java [docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html)

```
quit()
Quits this driver, closing every associated window.
```

Comment: Yes, this method is invoked after every TestSuite ends, still sometimes it happens to have some windows left open

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I had the same problem.

I kill the browsers tasks using CMD. I know this is the hard way but it works for me

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM IEDriverServer.exe /F");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM chromedriver-win.exe /F");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I already do that so for serial test case execution, but it will also close parallel running instances which is bad